# In Python, how can I search a list of elements for a value then also take the element before it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of elements created by:

```
if x > 2:
            pricePerUnit.append(name)
            pricePerUnit.append(price/quantity)
bestValue = list.count(min(pricePerUnit))
```

How could I take the element preceding each value at the same time as I take the value?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to structure your `pricePerUnit` list differently, storing both values together as a tuple:

```
if x > 2:
    pricePerUnit.append((name, price / quantity))
```

This way, when you find the best value item, you also find the name. To find the minimum value in the list, you now need to supply a `key` argument to `min`. This `key` function should extract the value to compare to find the minimum, which in this case is the 1st item in the tuple (`name` is the 0th item in the tuple):

```
bestValueName, bestValue = min(pricePerUnit, key=lambda ppu: ppu[1])
```

To find all of the items that have the best value, you should find the best value, and then find all items that have that value:

```
_, bestValue = min(pricePerUnit, key=lambda ppu: ppu[1])
bestValueItems = filter(lambda ppu: ppu[1] == bestValue, pricePerUnit)
```

Comment: the append function only takes one arguement though

Comment: Note the extra pair of parens inside the append call. This makes a tuple. If it is broken apart in to two statements like so, it should be clearer: `nameValueTuple = (name, price / quantity); pricePerUnit.append(nameValueTuple)`. The python docs have more information on tuples: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html

Comment: is there a way to make this work when there are multiple values that are the same?